# Extract list to a csv file

Tags: python

I need to extract to a .csv file a Dataframe that I extract from a website. I can generate the values ​​but I can't extract to .csv because of the following error:

```
AttributeError: object 'list' has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp?Data=23/01/2023&Data1=20230123&slcTaxa=PRE"
df  = pd.read_html(io=url, flavor='html5lib', encoding='latin1')
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:/Users/xport_dataframe.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: `Returns

    dfs

        A list of DataFrames.

`

Comment: `read_html()` reads HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects. [See docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have not made a data-frame, you just used pandas to create a list from html. Use df = pd.DataFrame(#list goes here) to create a dataframe, and then you can use df.to_csv(...

Answer (score 0):

`read_html` returns a list of dataframes (as explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)).
You need to concatenate this list into a Pandas dataframe prior to exporting it to csv:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp?Data=23/01/2023&Data1=20230123&slcTaxa=PRE"
list_of_dfs  = pd.read_html(io=url, flavor='html5lib', encoding='latin1')
print(df)
pd.concat(list_of_dfs).to_csv(r'C:/Users/xport_dataframe.csv', index=False, header=True)
```